# change canvas images

Tags: image, html, canvas

I like to change some canvas image (hat and jacket)

here is the code

```
document.ready = function() {

canvas = document.getElementById('canvasspace');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawImage();

}

function drawImage(){

    var tempimage = new Image();
    tempimage.src = jackets_images[jacket_to_draw];
    tempimage.onload = function (){ ctx.drawImage(tempimage, 0, 0); };

    var tempimage2 = new Image();
    tempimage2.src = hats_images[hat_to_draw];
    tempimage2.onload = function (){ ctx.drawImage(tempimage2, 0, 0); };    
}
```

the two image show up one over the other one, but making 2 time the code with 2 new Image(); does not seem fine to my eye ! but i dont know better.. please show me the light

Comment: Oh, you WANT to layer them? I thought I read that you DIDNT want them to layer?

Comment: ctx.drawImage() should not be clearing the canvas each time. Are you sure your source images have alpha channels? Maybe when you draw the second one, you are just covering up the canvas because of a lack of alpha?

Comment: bwcause of the confusion... here is the new code... see up !

Comment: Your question was about layering images on a canvas, which you see to have figured out already. I think you are now asking just how to do it in a loop?

Comment: RIGHT.... if i use the same     var tempimage = new Image();
it just overrite the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var imageNames = new Array();
imageNames[0] = jackets_images[jacket_to_draw];
imageNames[1] = hats_images[hat_to_draw];

var drawnImages = new Array();

function drawImage(images) {
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        drawnImages[i] = new Image();
        drawnImages[i].src = images[i];
        drawnImages[i].onload = function (){ 
            var thisImg = drawnImages[i];
            ctx.drawImage(thisImg, 0, 0); 
        };  
    }
}
```